# Why is there a random space when you click on this button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to replicate some material design buttons but have run into an issue with the div that is generated to create the "ripple" effect. If you go to my codepen at https://codepen.io/AlexStiles/pen/oPomzX you will see the issue.

This is caused by the div (I tried deleting it and it fixed the problem). I have tried adding a variety of properties such as font-size and line-height to no avail. Interestingly, depending on your browser the issue seems to have a different effect. On safari the width increases hugely then it decreases to the chrome width.

```js
"use strict";

const buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
const overlay = document.getElementsByClassName("overlay");
const animationTime = 600;

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", createRipple);
};

let circle = document.createElement("div");

function createRipple(e) {

    this.appendChild(circle);

    var d = Math.max(this.scrollWidth, this.scrollHeight);

    circle.style.width = circle.style.height = d + "px";

    circle.style.left = e.clientX - this.offsetLeft - d / 2 + "px";
    circle.style.top = e.clientY - this.offsetTop -  d / 2 + "px";

    circle.classList.add("ripple");
    // setTimeout(function(){
    //     for (let i = 0; i < circle.length; i++)
    //     document.getElementsByClassName("ripple")[i].remove();
    // }, animationTime);
}
```

```css
button {
    background-color: #4888f1;
    border-radius: 24px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    outline: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 10px 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

button .ripple {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    transform: scale(0);
    animation: ripple 0.5s linear;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}

@keyframes ripple {
    to {
        transform: scale(2.5);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

button img {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

button *:not(:last-child) {
    margin: 0 8px 0 0;
}

button span {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Futura;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
    button {
        padding: 0.8vw 1.75vw;
        border-radius: 1.9vw;
    } button img {
        width: 1.55vw;
        height: auto;
    } button span {
        font-size: 0.8vw;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Material Design Components</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <button>
        <span>Add to Cart</span>
    </button>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: It's weird - that space appears the first time you click the button, but vanishes and never appears again when you click it a second time

Comment: I don't know what browser you're using, but for chrome and safari on mac it doesn't collapse fully just mostly. It's still there.

Comment: If you take off the `margin: 0 8px 0 0;` it goes away.  So change to `margin: 0 0 0 0;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
button *:not(:last-child) {
    margin: 0 8px 0 0;
}
```

To,

```
button *:not(:last-child) {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

Checked in firefox.

Comment: I changed it to margin: 0 0 0 8px; to keep the spacing (I have an icon on my local version). Works great, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, on safari there is still a massive increase in width for the first click, could you find a reason for that. I need to wait at least 5 minutes to accept your answer (stackoverflow rules).

Comment: @AlexStiles in safari did you try removing `button *:not(:last-child)`

Comment: Yes, it makes no difference. I suspect it might have something to do with the javascript. Might just be an annoying quirk. I will wait until the answers slow and if nobody has any ideas I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you add the ripple element you make it the `last-child` thus the rule of margin `button *:not(:last-child)` will apply to span since this one is no more the last child.

To fix this remove margin from the span:

```js
"use strict";

const buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
const overlay = document.getElementsByClassName("overlay");
const animationTime = 600;

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", createRipple);
};

let circle = document.createElement("div");

function createRipple(e) {

    this.appendChild(circle);

    var d = Math.max(this.scrollWidth, this.scrollHeight);

    circle.style.width = circle.style.height = d + "px";

    circle.style.left = e.clientX - this.offsetLeft - d / 2 + "px";
    circle.style.top = e.clientY - this.offsetTop -  d / 2 + "px";

    circle.classList.add("ripple");
    // setTimeout(function(){
    //     for (let i = 0; i < circle.length; i++)
    //     document.getElementsByClassName("ripple")[i].remove();
    // }, animationTime);
}
```

```css
button {
    background-color: #4888f1;
    border-radius: 24px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    outline: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 10px 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

button .ripple {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    transform: scale(0);
    animation: ripple 0.5s linear;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}

@keyframes ripple {
    to {
        transform: scale(2.5);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

button img {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

button *:not(:last-child) {
    margin: 0 8px 0 0;
}

button span:first-child {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Futura;
    margin:0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
    button {
        padding: 0.8vw 1.75vw;
        border-radius: 1.9vw;
    } button img {
        width: 1.55vw;
        height: auto;
    } button span {
        font-size: 0.8vw;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Material Design Components</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <button>
        <span>Add to Cart</span>
    </button>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
</html>
```